# Navigate back to Homepage #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a Wordpress custom theme. It is a one pager but with 8 sub-pages. My question is how i can navigate to a specific section with and ID (example `<a href="#how">how</a>` from to sub-pages to the main-page (Homepage) in the navigation bar? I use twitter bootstrap framework and for wordpress navigation the Bootstrap Nav Walker.

My Javascript (main.js) to scroll down to a section is this below:

```
/*
 * Scroll to section
 */
$('body').on('click', '.section-link > a, .section-link', function () {
    scrollToSection($(this).attr('href'));

    return false;
});
if (window.location.hash) {
    scrollToSection(window.location.hash);
}

function scrollToSection(id) {

    var number = 0;

    if(! $('body').hasClass('scrolled')) {
        number = $('header.site-header').height() + 40;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - $('.navbar-fixed-top').height() - number
    }, 500);
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: try to set home url in `<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>/#how">`  and use current JS functionality.

Comment: htmlbrewery but without the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom links for your navigation then just hardcode the URL plus the hash id of your target div:

[image]

Then add the following code to your JS:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  scrollToSection(window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for help.

@htmlbrewery I don't understand correctly. Where should i set the home url? in what file, header.php ? 

I need a Option where i can put the IDs inside te URL input in the Wordpress Backend like in the Screenshot below.

http://prntscr.com/dx3knz

Comment: WordPress function `home url('/')` get home url.